# XML: XElement.Parse is Throwing an Exception

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I've got a list of xml strings that I need to parse and load into a c# class.  I'm getting null reference exceptions and think the "root" cause of it are the namespaces used in the xml.  I'm not well versed in ling to xml, so please offer alternatives if this solution looks bad.

Here's the parsing code:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.example.com/schema/msc/message";
XNamespace ns2 = "http://www.example.com/schema/msc/referral";

// data is List<string>
Parallel.ForEach(data, item =>
{
   var root = XElement.Parse(item);
   var dto = new DTO
       {
         RoutingCode = (string)root.Element("Message")
               .Element(ns + "Params")
               .Element(ns + "Events")
               .Attribute("Code")
         User = new UserDTO
                    {
                     AccountName = (string)root.Element("Message")
                                  .Element("Params")
                                  .Element("Events")
                                  .Element("ref:User")
                                  .Element("Name")
                    }
       };
     list.Add(dto);
});
```

Here's a sample xml element (reduced in size for readability)

```
<Message xmlns="http://www.example.com/schema/msc/message">
  <Params> 
    <Events xmlns="http://www.example.com/schema/msc/referral" Code="AC">
      <ref:User xmlns:ref="http://www.example.com/schema/msc/referral" Name="asdf"/>
    </Events>
  </Parama>
</Message>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things here.

1. As Martin Honnen points out, you are using `XElement.Parse`.  This means that `root` in your case *is* `Message` and will not have a child element by that name.
2. You are using namespaces correctly to get the routing code, but you are ignoring them to populate the `UserDTO`. The names should be, for example, `ns + Params` and `ns2 + User`.
3. The user's name is an *attribute*, not an *element*.

Another suggestion I would make is not to 'leave the monad' early.  Use the methods that return `IEnumerable<T>` until you don't have to.  So prefer `root.Elements(ns + "Params").Elements(ns + "Events").SingleOrDefault()` to `root.Element(ns + "Params").Element(ns +"Events")`.  This avoids the null reference exceptions.

Putting this all together, we get something like this:

```
XNamespace message = "http://www.example.com/schema/msc/message";
XNamespace referral = "http://www.example.com/schema/msc/referral";

var root = XElement.Parse(xml);

var dto = new
{
    RoutingCode = (string) root.Elements(message + "Params")
        .Elements(referral + "Events")
        .Attributes("Code")
        .Single(),
    User = new
    {
        AccountName = (string) root.Elements(message + "Params")
            .Elements(referral + "Events")
            .Elements(referral + "User")
            .Attributes("Name")
            .Single()
    }
};
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4tlRny) for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `XElement.Parse` and not `XDocument.Parse` then your `root` element is the `Message` element and any selection of children should start with the `Params` element.

```
     RoutingCode = (string)root.Element(ns + "Params")
           .Element(ns2 + "Events")
           .Attribute("Code")
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I'm still getting the exception.  Any way I can do a better job getting debug info instead of catching the Exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to retrieve attributes.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

XNamespace ns = "http://www.example.com/schema/msc/referral";

doc.Descendants(ns + "Events")
    .Select(e => new DTO {
                            RoutingCode = (string)e.Attribute("Code"),
                            User = new UserDTO((string)e.Element(ns + "User").Attribute("Name"))
                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try linking the namespace to the XElement

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string item =
                "<Message xmlns=\"http://www.example.com/schema/msc/message\">" +
                  "<Params>" +
                    "<Events xmlns=\"http://www.example.com/schema/msc/referral\" Code=\"AC\">" +
                      "<ref:User xmlns:ref=\"http://www.example.com/schema/msc/referral\" Name=\"asdf\"/>" +
                    "</Events>" +
                  "</Params>" +
                "</Message>";

            XElement root = XElement.Parse(item);
            XNamespace ns1 = root.Name.Namespace;
            XNamespace ns2 = root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Events").FirstOrDefault().Name.Namespace;

        }
    }
}​
```